# F# charting example

Tags: f#, charts

I would like to do some basic charting in F# using build in features or a free library. 
And I would be very very pleased  with a very basic example of it, a pie chart if possible.

Example data :

```
[("John",34);("Sara",30);("Will",20);("Maria",16)]
```

Where the ints are percentages to be represented in the pie.

I have recently installed VSLab and though I find a lot of 3D examples, I am only looking for a simple pie chart...

It is also fine to use excel features by the way, not free, but installed nevertheless..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's something I smashed together using the Google Chart API,
I hope the code is clear enough without further explanation:

```
//Built with F# 1.9.7.8
open System.IO
open System.Net
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions
//Add references for the namespaces below if you're not running this code in F# interactive
open System.Drawing 
open System.Windows.Forms 

let buildGoogleChartUri input =
    let chartWidth, chartHeight = 250,100

    let labels,data = List.unzip input
    let dataString = 
        data 
        |> List.map (box>>string) //in this way, data can be anything for which ToString() turns it into a number
        |> List.toArray |> String.concat ","

    let labelString = labels |> List.toArray |> String.concat "|"

    sprintf "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=%dx%d&chd=t:%s&cht=p3&chl=%s"
            chartWidth chartHeight dataString labelString

//Bake a bitmap from the google chart URI
let buildGoogleChart myData =
    async {
        let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(buildGoogleChartUri myData)
        let! response = req.AsyncGetResponse()
        return new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream())
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously

//invokes the google chart api to build a chart from the data, and presents the image in a form
//Excuse the sloppy winforms code
let test() =
    let myData = [("John",34);("Sara",30);("Will",20);("Maria",16)]

    let image = buildGoogleChart myData
    let frm = new Form()
    frm.BackgroundImage <- image
    frm.BackgroundImageLayout <- ImageLayout.Center
    frm.ClientSize <- image.Size
    frm.Show()
```

Comment: +1 for your effort, no time to go into in now, I will except it laterif it works

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do "made in home" pie chart:
    open System.Drawing

```
let red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red) in
let green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green) in
let blue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue) in
let rec colors =
  seq {
    yield red
    yield green
    yield blue
    yield! colors
  }


let pie data (g: Graphics) (r: Rectangle) =
  let vals = 0.0 :: List.map snd data
  let total = List.sum vals
  let angles = List.map (fun v -> v/total*360.0) vals
  let p = new Pen(Color.Black,1)
  Seq.pairwise vals |> Seq.zip colors |> Seq.iter (fun (c,(a1,a2)) -> g.DrawPie(p,r,a1,a2); g.FillPie(c,r,a1,a2))
```

Comment: +1 probably not the one I will end up using, but kudos for home cooking!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but technology changing.

in vs 2013, F# 3, and installing the nuget Package

```
 Install-Package FSharp.Charting
```

Add reference to:

```
    System.Windows.Forms
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
```

and with one line of code:

```
     Application.Run ((Chart.Pie data).ShowChart())
```

The following F# code generate the bie chart:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open FSharp.Charting

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =  
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault false   
    let data =[("John",34);("Sara",30);("Will",20);("Maria",16)]      
    Application.Run ((Chart.Pie data).ShowChart())
    0
```

and you get the following chart:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Originally I only tried to complement **ssp's** example here with a very simple windows form dialog which shows a pie. But trying this I found a bug in ssp's code: on the one hand `Seq.pairwise` operates on `vals` instead of `angles` and on the other hand it obviously doesn't consider that pie slices will be drawn beginning from start angle along sweep angle.

I corrected the bug, commented, rearranged, reformatted and renamed some things - and made it both `#load`-able in *fsi.exe* and *compilable* with *fsc.exe*:

```
#light
module YourNamespace.PieExample

open System
open System.Drawing
open System.ComponentModel
open System.Windows.Forms

(* (circular) sequence of three colors *)
#nowarn "40"
let red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)
let green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green)
let blue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
let rec colors =
    seq { yield red
          yield green
          yield blue
          yield! colors }

(* core function to build up and show a pie diagram *)
let pie data (g: Graphics) (r: Rectangle) =
    // a pen for borders of pie slices
    let p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0f)
    // retrieve pie shares from data and sum 'em up
    let vals  = List.map snd data
    let total = List.sum vals
    // baking a pie starts here with ...
    vals
    // scaling vals in total to a full circle
    |> List.map (fun v -> v * 360.0 / total)
    // transform list of angles to list of pie slice delimiting angles
    |> List.scan (+) 0.0
    // turn them into a list of tuples consisting of start and end angles
    |> Seq.pairwise
    // intermix the colors successively
    |> Seq.zip colors 
    // and at last do FillPies and DrawPies with these ingredients
    |> Seq.iter (fun (c,(starta,enda))
                     -> g.FillPie(c,r,(float32 starta)
                                     ,(float32 (enda - starta)))
                        g.DrawPie(p,r,(float32 starta)
                                     ,(float32 (enda - starta))))

(* demo data *)
let demolist = [ ("a", 1.); ("b", 2.); ("c", 3.);
                 ("d", 2.); ("e", 2.); ("f", 2.) ]

(* finally a simple resizable form showing demo data as pie with 6 slices *)
let mainform = new Form(MinimumSize = Size(200,200))
// add two event handlers
mainform.Paint.Add (fun e -> pie demolist e.Graphics mainform.ClientRectangle)
mainform.Resize.Add (fun _ -> mainform.Invalidate())
#if COMPILED
Application.Run(mainform)
#else
mainform.ShowDialog() |> ignore
#endif
```

Last but not least I want to mention two helpful hints I found useful

- [in a *stackoverflow.com* answer by **ildjarn**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479072/f-sequence-of-running-total/5479126#5479126) where he shows stunning (at least for me) usage of `List.scan`
- [at a *c-sharpcorner.com* blog by **Shalini Juneja**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/6106/how-to-draw-pie-shape-in-fsharp-window-application.aspx) where she shows how to create and draw a simple resizeable windows forms dialog with F# (in fact she also shows how to display a pie)