# f# sequence of running total

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Ok, this looks like it should be easy, but I'm just not getting it. If I have a sequence of numbers, how do I generate a new sequence made up of the running totals? eg for a sequence [1;2;3;4], I want to map it to [1;3;6;10]. In a suitably functional way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`List.scan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.scan%5b%27t%2c%27state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
let runningTotal = List.scan (+) 0 >> List.tail

[1; 2; 3; 4]
|> runningTotal
|> printfn "%A"
```

[`Seq.scan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.scan%5b%27t%2c%27state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)-based implementation:

```
let runningTotal seq' = (Seq.head seq', Seq.skip 1 seq') ||> Seq.scan (+)

{ 1..4 }
|> runningTotal
|> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: This is very cool, however I was hoping to do this for a Sequence rather than a list.

Comment: @Aidan : Edited to add proper Seq.scan implementation.

Comment: Cool, that's the one. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Another variation using `Seq.scan` (`Seq.skip 1` gets rid of the leading zero):

```
> {1..4} |> Seq.scan (+) 0 |> Seq.skip 1;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 3; 6; 10]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, F# feeds my sickness for succinct, elegant solutions.

Comment: Me too. I fear my fate as a programmer is intertwined with F#.

Answer (score 5):

```
> Seq.scan (fun acc n -> acc + n) 0 [1;2;3;4];;
val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 1; 3; 6; ...]
```

With lists:

```
> [1;2;3;4] |> List.scan (fun acc n -> acc + n) 0 |> List.tail;;
val it : int list = [1; 3; 6; 10]
```

Edit: Another way with sequences:

```
let sum s = seq {
    let x = ref 0
    for i in s do
        x := !x + i
        yield !x
}
```

Yes, there's a mutable variable, but I find it more readable (if you want to get rid of the leading 0).

Comment: cool, thank you. However it seems to generate a larger sequence, with an initial 0, do it doesn't feel like a true map.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it was worthwhile to share how to do this with [Record Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records) in case that's also what you came here looking for.

Below is a fictitious example demonstrating the concept using runner laps around a track.

```
type Split = double
type Lap = { Num : int; Split : Split }
type RunnerLap = { Lap : Lap; TotalTime : double }

let lap1 = { Num = 1; Split = 1.23 } 
let lap2 = { Num = 2; Split = 1.13 } 
let lap3 = { Num = 3; Split = 1.03 } 
let laps = [lap1;lap2;lap3]

let runnerLapsAccumulator =  
  Seq.scan 
    (fun rl l -> { rl with Lap = l; TotalTime = rl.TotalTime + l.Split }) // acumulator
    { Lap = { Num = 0; Split = 0.0 }; TotalTime = 0.0 } // initial state

let runnerLaps = laps |> runnerLapsAccumulator
printfn "%A" runnerLaps
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way but it should do the trick

```
  let input = [1; 2; 3; 4]
  let runningTotal = 
    (input, 0) 
    |> Seq.unfold (fun (list, total) ->
      match list with
      | [] -> 
        None
      | h::t -> 
        let total = total + h
        total, (t, total) |> Some)
    |> List.ofSeq
```